# getServerSideProps or getStaticProps is not getting called if I use the component as markup in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just started with the `NextJS`. I have created two pages `PageA` and `PageB`. Here is the code

**PageB**

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import axios from 'axios';

const PageB: NextPage = ({ data = [] }: any) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <thead>
            <tr style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <th style={{ width: "20%" }}>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          {/* rows */}
          <tbody>
            {
              data.map((post: any) => {
                return <tr key={post._id}>
                  <td>{post.name}</td>
                </tr>;
              })
            }
          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps  = async ({ query }) => {
  const myData = await axios.get(`http://localhost:443/api/data`);
  return { data: myData.data };
}
export default PageB;
```

and **PageA** that will use **PageB**

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import axios from 'axios';
import PageB from '../pageb';

const PageA: NextPage = ({ chats }: any) => {
  return (
        <div>
          <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <thead>
              <tr style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <th style={{ width: "50%" }}>Sender Id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            {/* rows */}
            <tbody>
              {
                chats.map((chat: any) => {
                  return <tr key={chat._id}>
                    <td>{chat.sender_id}</td>
                  </tr>;
                })
              }
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      <PageB></PageB>
    </>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps  = async ({ query }) => {
  const chats = await axios.get(`http://localhost:443/api/chats`);
  // console.log(posts);
  return { chats: chats.data };
}


export default PageA;
```

Now **PageB** shows the empty list. And if i directly redirect to the `/pageb` it shows the data.

what is the problem?

Comment: My guess is that when pageB is used as a component, it doesn't call getInitialProps. You should avoid importing page in other page in nextJS, if you need to import it you can make a component outside of the page folder

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier, i was using Angular before, i want to reuse this component, how can  i do this?

Comment: Get it outside of page folder (component folder for example), put the getInitialProps of page B in page A, and send it as props to your newly created component. You will be able to use your newly created component in page B aswell. Anything reusable should not belong to page folder, it's just the skeleton of your webpage